# Audio not Working Correctly

Tags: java

The last time I asked how to use background audio correctly, I was told I had to use a thread. Now, I have done that, yet I still have the same problem: It does not run the rest of the program until the song completes, yet I need it to play in the background! help anyone? (Sorry for no comments in the code. If you all really feel there needs to be some to help you out I will update it with comments).

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class PokemonDemo3 implements LineListener
{
   private boolean done = false;

public  void update(LineEvent event) 
{
    if(event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP || event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.CLOSE) 
    {
         done = true;
    }
}

public void waitonfinish() throws InterruptedException 
{
  while(!done) 
  {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
  } 
}

public static void playSound(final String url) 
{
    try 
    {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(url));
        PokemonDemo3 control = new PokemonDemo3();
        clip.addLineListener(control);
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();
        control.waitonfinish();

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String holder;
    int response;
    String[] options = {"Boy", "Girl"};

    Pokemon intro = new Pokemon();
    playSound("/Users/2018658/Desktop/pokemon.wav");
 }
```

Comment: Don't use a uncontrolled loop and `Thread.sleep`, you're likely blocking the event dispatching thread of your ui framework.  Why do you need to wait until the song completes?  What do you want to do when it's done?  Maybe you should use an observer pattern instead

Comment: I honestly don't know what that is... do you have a link to help me figure it out? And I don't need it to wait: that's the problem. It is waiting, instead of playing in the background.

Comment: The whole loop is a bad idea. You should use the LineListener's update method to trigger some kind callback to notify who ever is interested that the clip has completed, this way, you won't be blocking the Curren thread

Comment: I cannot mark best answer, as you commented and did not put an answer. If you just put some sort of answer I can resolve this.